# Beginners Database Design - Weak Entity

Tags: sql, database, entity, entity-relationship, erd

[image]

If I have a design like the image above, and I wanted to have another table called "favourite fruit" that selects only one fruit for each person, would it make sense to have it as a weak entity of fruit table with a `pk (personid UNIQUE, fruitid, artificialid UNIQUE)` ?

Comment: If you only have one favorite fruit per person, you can probably use the `person` table itself to store that info. If you still need to have a separate table, the `personid` column itself (or the combo of `personid` and `fruitid`) should be enough to uniquely identify each row of the table, and you shouldn't need `artificialid`.

Comment: `favorite fruit` in this case would be a relationship between `person` and `fruits`, not a weak entity.

Comment: Lets say that I have an issue where I add an attribute called favouritefruit as a fk pointing to the fruitid in fruits, but the fruits table has no tuple with the fruitid in it. Wouldn't that cause a back-forth referencing error? Furthermore, each person has to have only 1 favourite fruit (no less no more). Also, for further clarification, the fruits tables shows fruits that the person owns.

Answer (score 0):

Watch it/Stay tuned. Entities only exist in the diagram if they have properties/attributes, even in partitioning relationships (the "ISA" relationship).

> [...] and I wanted to have another table called "favourite fruit [...]"

Be careful too. In the Conceptual Model, there are no tables, but entities. Just as entities, relationships can later become tables too. You may get confused to use such terminology at this stage.

It's just like the user [reaanb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532721/reaanb) said in the comments. Relations/relationships express exactly this: relationships between things (in case, entities). You need to remember why you build relationships in the diagram. Always ask yourself:

*Why this relationship exists? Why I'm creating this between X and Y? Do I really need to persist this?*

You can without any problems create more than one relationship between two entities, since they represent different things (relationships).

Now. If you know that a user has a favorite fruit, then you know that these two entities are related in some way. Therefore, without a doubt, we have a relationship.

In your case, if a user always has a favorite fruit, then we have a 1-N relationship, where the N part is in users, as a fruit can be the favorite of many users.

On the other hand, if a user may or may not have a favorite fruit and you do not want a field with nullable value, we have to define a N-N relationship. This relationship will become a table when decomposed. In this case you'll have a table with only two columns. The two are foreign keys for the two tables, "users" and "fruits", and they will also be a composite primary key on this table. For it is not possible to repeat records, in the case, more than one user with a favorite fruit, set the "user" column as unique.

If you have any questions, please comment and I will answer.